# Java library to get different declinaison of a word (nlp ?)

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

For a simple project in Java I would need a library that from a given words it returns me a list of its declinaison (including plural, singular, adjective etc..)

As an example something like this:

```
"Photo" -> "Photo", "Photograph", photography" 
"Walks" -> "Walk", "Walking" ...
```

I had a look at lib like CoreNLP but I cannot figure out how to achieve this kind of stuff? Plus the doc is kind of bad and I cannot hardly find any nice code example.

Could someone help with this?

Comment: Can I just ask what the precise problem is you're trying to solve? The reverse process of what you're trying to do (i.e. some kind of stemming or lemmatization) is much more common, so we should determine if that could be an answer to your problem.

Comment: Off course! In brief: In our database we have a list of tags (words of all kinds, they are all small letters). Then we a places that are described by these tags.  
The reason why I'm looking for such a lib. is that I receive a list of words (for example let's say words pulled for "likes" of a Facebook account. I would like to match these words against our tag database. At the moment it's very basic and does a simple "=". So i wanted to improved a bit and transform the word from this list into its variation so there would be chance that they match the tags in our database.

Comment: OK, so if I understand the idea correctly, it sounds like stemming could be a solution: you stem all words (the words in your database and the words that you want to compare them against), so that "walks" is mapped to its stem "walk", for example. Then you use these stems to match the words rather than the original word forms. Would that work?